# How detect when a cell is removed from a uitableview in iOS for this edge case?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am able to detect when a cell is removed from the *UITableView* by writing a handler for the method *tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:*.  This method is called whenever a cell is removed from the display.  However, there is one exception.

When the cell has a *UITextField* and the field is the first responder, this method is never called even when it's scrolled off the display and the cells immediately before it and after it are.

The cell is also confirmed to be removed from the *UITableView* with a test while the cell is scrolled off the screen.  The call to *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* returns nil under this condition.

I also subclassed the *UITableViewCell* and wrote a handler for removeFromSuperView.  Again this method is called for all the cells when the are scrolled off the screen except when the cell has a *UITextField* and it is the first responder.

Another thing to note is that the *UITextField* in the cell accepts key input while it is scrolled off the screen and the call to *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* returns nil.  I can see this when the cell is scrolled back into view.

Does anyone have any solutions for detecting when the cell is scrolled out of view, so that the controller can get access to the *UITextField*?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to resign your first responder manually **before** the cell disappears.  Depending on your requirements, this could be done in multiple ways, usually when the user starts scrolling. You could restore the first responder after he finishes scrolling, if the cell is still visible. Probably better from the graphical design point of view as well.

Alternatively, you could try to implement delegate's `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and make a previous visible cells set, which you'd intersect with tableview's visibleCells array. The elements that are not in the current visibleCells but are in the previous were removed. Then assign a **copy** of visibleCells to previousVisibleCells.

This is probably a bug in Apple's code, you could file a radar for it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I've been struggling with this because I felt there should be a simple solution to this one.  Your reply made me think again about the UIScollView Class and the delegate. When looking through the methods, I noticed the keyboardDismissMode property. One of the values is UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag.   I went back to UIBuilder and set the value for the table view to dismiss keyboard on drag.  Voila, this forces the UITextField to resign first responder without any code.  It's a perfect solution for my need.  Perfect!!!

Comment: That's awesome. Didn't knew about that one. Thanks for sharing.